# java.lang.IllegalStateException in Android 3.x and 4.x ; Works fine on 2.x

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I am using `TabActivity` which contains Four tabs.  For every tab I am using `ActivityGroup` and inside `ActivityGroup` I have several activities.  In one of my `Activity` I have a Google Map.  Whenever I click on the built in Back button in Google Map `Activity` I am getting the below Exception.

> android java.lang.illegalstateexception can not perform this action after onsaveinstancestate.

I am getting the above Exception in 3.x and 4.x Android versions.  But in 2.x it is working fine without any Exception.

Comment: this error is triggered when committing a fragment transaction after onsavestate is called but you are not talking about fragments

Comment: First all ActivityGroup and TabActivity are now deprecated, second Can you post your Activity code or at least your onSaveInstanceState method?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code. Otherwise, no point of discussion.

As far as I know, you may pass wrong parameters or using the same API twice.

Answer (score 0):

are you using startmanaging cursor anywhere in the code for this activity.
This works fines for 2.3 OS but 3.0 onwards it throws error. I also faced same situation, the way to resolve is the add startmanaging cursor only in 2.3 below OS.